# MFC: Is there any way to active button without On_Bn_Clicked() event?

Tags: button, mfc

I have a task that are hiding a dialog but I need to click the button belong to this dialog to
implement some function before go to the next dialog.

But when I hide this dialog, I can't click the button. Is there any way to implement this button without On_Bn_Clicked() event? I mean that when the dialog is called, the button is also activated.

Thank for the helps.

Comment: Why do you want to click a button without using the event handler. If I misunderstood your question just use SendMessage with the WM_COMMAND code and the action behind the button takes place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the button a few Windows messages are sent.  The important ones are WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP which tells the button you clicked the left mouse button down and up.  Then some time later a WM_COMMAND message is sent to the parent window to handle the button click.  At that point your ON_COMMAND() MFC handler is called.  MFC abstracts this all away from you for the most part.

You could go and simulate this using the Win32 SendMessage API but if the message pump is blocking your button may not be clicked when you think it will.  If you want a quick answer to your question then this is an approach to "get it done".  It would look something like this:

`SendMessage(button.GetSafeHwnd(), WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, 0);
SendMessage(button.GetSafeHwnd(), WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, 0);`

I think a more sensible approach is to take the code that is in this On_Bn_Clicked() event handler and simply move it to a reusable function.  This way you can call the code in On_Bn_Clicked() from anywhere in your program.

Comment: Using SendMessage on Windows input messages isn't a "real good" idea. When using this, you can also use SendMessage with the WM_COMMAND message.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I fixed this problem. Just implement the code but not take them to On_Bn_Clicked().

Answer (score 0):

Just call On_Bn_Clicked() directly from your code. There is no harm in doing so. (I suppose you don't want to actually click the hidden button with the mouse...)

Comment: Yes but i just implement the code, don't need to call On_Bn_Clicked(). Thanks you, i solved my question :)